# limitTo: not working in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, loops, limit

AngularJS

```
userData.success(function (userdataobject) {
                  $scope.catadata = userdataobject;
                $scope.quantity = 1;
            });
            userData.success(function (userdataobject) {
                  $scope.catadata1 = userdataobject;
                $scope.quantity1 = 1;
            });
```

AngularJS 2 different Loops code

Loop-1

```
 <div ng-repeat="cat in catadata | limitTo:quantity | filter: {TopCategoryID : 11}">
```

Loop-2

```
<div ng-repeat="cat1 in catadata1 | limitTo:quantity1 | filter: {TopCategoryID : 12}">
```

`limitTo:quantity`  is working but `limitTo:quantity1` is not working

Comment: I use limitTo: after filter: , now its working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TLDR:** You will have to move the `limitTo` filter to the end:

```
<div ng-repeat="cat1 in catadata1 | filter: {TopCategoryID : 12} | limitTo:quantity1">
```

The [`limitTo` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) will create a new array with the desired length, then your filter will be applied, consider this:

```
var catadata1 = [
    {TopCategoryID: 13, ...},
    {TopCategoryID: 42, ...},
    {TopCategoryID: 12, ...},
    ...
];
// When we apply the limitTo, this is what's happening:
var limitTo = catadata1.slice(0, 1); // Keep the first item
// And when we apply the filter we only filter on the limitTo array:
var filter = limitTo.filter(matchItem({TopCategoryID : 12}));
```

Another way to look at is:

```
var a = [0, 1, 2]; // Initial Array
var b = [0] // limitTo: 1
var c = [] // filter: 2
```

While:

```
var a = [0, 1, 2]; // Initial Array
var b = [0] // limitTo: 1
var c = [0] // filter: 0
```

This is what is happening in your code, just with another filter.

Comment: Thank You, I use limitTo: after filter: , now its working

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you have referenced the same array and the first loop is executed first. Try to copy the array before assigning it to the scope. Example:

```
userData.success(function (userdataobject) {
    $scope.catadata = angular.copy(userdataobject);
    $scope.quantity = 1;
});
userData.success(function (userdataobject) {
    $scope.catadata1 = angular.copy(userdataobject);
    $scope.quantity1 = 1;
});
```

If this does not solve your problem please create a Plunker in which you will reproduce the scenario.

Comment: Note that `.copy`  will make a deep copy, this is in most cases not necessary, instead make a shallow clone (Only duplicate the outer most layer of the Object/Array): For arrays you can simply write: `var new_array = old_array.slice()`

Comment: Yes, I completely agree. Thanks.